# Update with expression instead of value

Tags: mongodb

I am totally new to MongoDB... I am missing a "newbie" tag, so the experts would not have to see this question.

I am trying to update all documents in a collection using an expression. The query I was expecting to solve this was:

```
db.QUESTIONS.update({}, { $set: { i_pp : i_up * 100 - i_down * 20 } }, false, true);
```

That, however, results in the following error message:

> ReferenceError: i_up is not defined (shell):1

At the same time, the database did not have any problem with eating this one:

```
db.QUESTIONS.update({}, { $set: { i_pp : 0 } }, false, true);
```

Do I have to do this one document at a time or something? That just seems excessively complicated.

**Update**
Thank you Sergio Tulentsev for telling me that it does not work. Now, I am really struggling with how to do this. I offer 500 [Profit Points](http://open-org.com/profit-sharing) to the helpful soul, who can write this in a way that MongoDB understands. If you register on [our forum](http://forum.open-org.com) I can add the Profit Points to your account there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use expressions in updates. Or, rather, you can't use expressions that depend on fields of the document. Simple self-containing math expressions are fine (e.g. `2 * 2`).

If you want to set a new field for all documents that is a function of other fields, you have to loop over them and update manually. Multi-update won't help here.

Comment: Couldn't you send a bit of `db.questions.find(...).forEach(function(q) { /* db.questions.update(...) to patch 'q' in-place */ })` JavaScript into MongoDB to avoid leaving the database? I've done similar things to avoid round-tripping out of the database.

Comment: @muistooshort: Theoretically, you could. I haven't done this myself.

Comment: I just did a few tests and it seems to work, [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors) even suggest that `db.questions.find(...)` will be a cursor so it won't try to instantiate a whole array for the `forEach` call.

Comment: Are you trying in the shell? I was more wondering what command I'd have to use in the (ruby) driver.

Comment: You can use `db.eval()` to send JavaScript straight in. I'll write it up as an answer later this evening, might be useful for future searchers.

Answer (score 8):

```js
//the only differnce is to make it look like and aggregation pipeline
db.table.updateMany({}, [{
      $set: {
        col3:{"$sum":["$col1","$col2"]}
      },
    }]
 )
```

Comment: Note that if you run this without the  surrounding `[]` (which indicate [an aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#std-label-update-many-method-agg-pipeline) as stated) then this will insert the literal value `{$sum: ["$col1", "$col2"]}` into the collection.

Comment: I get an error: `MongoServerError: BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'` Note I'm on MongoDb 3.6.6 . Is this technique newer than that?

Answer (score 7):

I just came across this while searching for the MongoDB equivalent of SQL like this:

```
update t
set c1 = c2
where ...
```

Sergio is correct that you can't reference another property as a value in a straight update. However, `db.c.find(...)` returns a [cursor and that cursor has a `forEach` method](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors):

> Queries to MongoDB return a cursor, which can be iterated to retrieve
>   results. The exact way to query will vary with language driver.
>   Details below focus on queries from the MongoDB shell (i.e. the
>   `mongo` process).
>
> The shell `find()` method returns a cursor object which we can then iterate to retrieve specific documents from the result. We use
>   `hasNext()` and `next()` methods for this purpose.
>
> ```
> for( var c = db.parts.find(); c.hasNext(); ) {
>    print( c.next());
> }
> ```
>
> Additionally in the shell, `forEach()` may be used with a cursor:
>
> ```
> db.users.find().forEach( function(u) { print("user: " + u.name); } );
> ```

So you can say things like this:

```
db.QUESTIONS.find({}, {_id: true, i_up: true, i_down: true}).forEach(function(q) {
    db.QUESTIONS.update(
        { _id: q._id },
        { $set: { i_pp: q.i_up * 100 - q.i_down * 20 } }
    );
});
```

to update them one at a time without leaving MongoDB.

If you're using a driver to connect to MongoDB then there should be some way to send a string of JavaScript into MongoDB; for example, with the Ruby driver you'd use [`eval`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/DB.html#eval-instance_method):

```
connection.eval(%q{
    db.QUESTIONS.find({}, {_id: true, i_up: true, i_down: true}).forEach(function(q) {
        db.QUESTIONS.update(
            { _id: q._id },
            { $set: { i_pp: q.i_up * 100 - q.i_down * 20 } }
        );
    });
})
```

Other languages should be similar.

Comment: eval is deprecated, what is the replacement or alternative? Simply execute it directly, without eval? Does it have the same effects?

Comment: @CaptainObvious: I don't use MongoDB anymore so I'm not sure. Does [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39312067/479863) help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/ states that eval is deprecated as well. Thanks for the effort though, I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Rha7 gave a good idea, but the code above is not work without defining a temporary variable.

This sample code produces an approximate calculation of the age (leap years behinds the scene) based on 'birthday' field and inserts the value into suitable field for all documents not containing such:

```
db.employers.find({age: {$exists: false}}).forEach(function(doc){
    var new_age = parseInt((ISODate() - doc.birthday)/(3600*1000*24*365));
    db.employers.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {age: new_age}});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Example to remove "00" from the beginning of  a caller id:

```
db.call_detail_records_201312.find(
    { destination: /^001/ }, 
    { "destination": true }
).forEach(function(row){
    db.call_detail_records_201312.update(
        { _id: row["_id"] },
        { $set: {
                destination: row["destination"].replace(/^001/, '1')
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Just update `row.destination` and use `row.save` instead `db.call...update(`

Comment: I'm very sorry: the correct sintax is `db.call.save(row)` instead `row.save`

Answer (score 0):

I did a self-referencing document expression like so on a different problem:

```
db.activities.find().forEach((row)=> { 
  db.activities.updateOne({
    _id: row._id
  }, {
    $set: {
      cost: row.cost * 1.35
    }
  });
  })
```

On Atlas free tier, this took a long time to execute,
at the rate of about 35 updates / second