# Executing mongodb scripts via mongoid Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongo db script in a js file:

query.js

```
//conn = new Mongo();
//db = conn.getDB("dbName");
functionFoo = function (arg){
    //----process arg
}
```

also I have an array of `args` known as `args_array`, (that I fetch from database using mongoid) for which I want to do something like this:

```
args_array.each do |arg|
   //some how call functionFoo(arg) from the query.js file
end
```

is this possible in rails?

I am able to execute the file from terminal but I want to wrap it in my application so that I can use it from rails console.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call JavaScript queries directly in Ruby; you'd have to pass through a JavaScript interpreter (eg. the `mongo` shell) in order for these to make sense. What's your actual requirement -- do you just need to evaluate a list of saved queries in a file, or do they have to be JavaScript functions?

Comment: I have a javascript function which updates loads of documents, its not a list of queries..
Had it been an independent script, I could have done it using `exec` may be, but the function takes an argument from a ruby array, this is my exact problem

Comment: You can still pass arguments with Ruby's `exec` and define these for your `mongo` shell script with [`--eval ... `](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption--eval). However, rather than using a mix of JavaScript + Ruby, I think it would be much more sensible to write all the functions in one language. You could either get the query arguments you need via JavaScript, or port your existing JavaScript functions to Ruby.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that...
Actually writing query in ruby will affect the time complexity in comparison to  query written in javascript. right?
As the query is long so I wrote the main part of query in javascript at the same time trying to make it accessible through the rails console somehow.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by time complexity of queries . If you are writing functions to run in the `mongo` shell, those are still executed on the client side similar to queries in Ruby. Spawning `mongo` shells to run functions & queries from the Rails console adds complexity & overhead if you could run those queries directly via the Ruby driver. The Ruby driver will also have richer I/O methods compared to the `mongo` shell. It would help if you can post an actual example of a function & query you are running and describe the intended goal. There is likely a more direct approach.

Answer (score 2):

I know this old question but in case you still need answer or any one else. This answer works with `gem mongo ~> 2.3`.

The key to answer you do not need mongoid in this case - in my case I use it for rails model, so I use mongoid (5.1.0) only to get DB connection `db = Mongoid.default_client.database` - or you can get/create database using mongo gem.

To execute javascript on database you need to call `command` method `db.command({ eval: 'js' })` or `db.command({ eval: 'function(n){return db.projects.find({name: n}).toArray();}', args: ['beskhai'], nolock: true })`

To get the result you can call `.documents` `db.command(...).documents`, The return is a hash {retval: it will be return of you script, ok: is 1 if success} the return object of `command` call is `[Mongo::Operation::Result]` https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/operation/result.rb.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MongoID 6.0.1, and it easy to query everything you want like that:

```
    db ||= Mongoid.default_client.database
    f = """
    functionFoo = function (arg){
    //----process arg
    }
    """
    result = db.command({:$eval => f, args: [arg1, arg2, ...arg_n], nolock: true})
    @result_data = result.first['retval']
```

It not only a function, just every thing you want to do with command.
My example is:

```
db ||= Mongoid.default_client.database
f = """
var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames(), stats = [];
collectionNames.forEach(function (n) { stats.push(db[n].stats()); });
stats = stats.sort(function(a, b) { return b['size'] - a['size']; });
return stats;
"""
result = db.command({:$eval => f, args: [], nolock: true})
@result_data = result.first['retval']
```